# BigQuery jobs.list in non-reverse order

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way I can get the list of jobs in chronological order? Right now when running a call to the jobs.list endpoint I get a list of jobs in reverse chronological order, I need them from newest (today) to earliest.

Any help would be great, I've already looked at the docs and can't find anything that allows sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get a list of jobs in reverse chronological order
>   I need them from newest (today) to earliest.

From `newest (today) to earliest` is exactly what you are getting right now - which is a `reverse chronological order`

There is no way to list jobs in a `chronological order` - but you do this just once  and than store it where you want to analyze it  - so this should not be a problem

Comment: Odd. When converting the time stamps they're for a while back. Not today.

Comment: check the way you convert them :o)

Comment: What format are the time stamps in? I used a millisecond converter.

Comment: #standardSQL      
SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(statistics.creationTime)

Comment: Maybe I'm not using the correct endpoint. Which one could I use to view info on queries that were run today?

Comment: what it is that you are using now?

Comment: yes - GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/projectId/jobs

Comment: So why are the queries I've run today not showing up?

Comment: make sure you provide correct project - is it possible you run today's queries in different project - jobs are listed under respective billing project!

Comment: I only have one project.

Comment: to troubleshoot  - open Web UI and click on `Query History` to see what you really have.

Comment: so, how it goes?

Comment: Seems like it was a conversion issue. I'm still having issues trying to find out why my bill is so high though... all my queries are billing tier 1 and not processing more than a gig or two of data.

Comment: Yes, needs to be in milliseconds in order to convert.

Comment: sure  - as i pointed already :o) - #standardSQL SELECT TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(statistics.creationTime)